# Remove trailing newline

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-replace

I've a MySQL database from which I extract a string which is a list of words separated by newline. Now I want to remove only the trailing
newline.

I tried using preg_replace as

```
$string = preg_replace('/\n/','',$string);
```

It works, but all the newlines in the strings are removed :(

How can I do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You need to add the end of line anchor:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\n$/','',$string);
```

It's better to ***avoid*** regular expressions for such a simple substitution. This can easily be done using [**rtrim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) as:

```
$string = rtrim($string);
```

`rtrim` without the second argument will remove the trailing whitespace characters which include:

- newline
- space
- vertical tab
- horizontal tab
- carriage return

Comment: Does this remove all     whitespace, or only last?

Comment: rtrim removes all trailing whitespaces

Answer (score 13):

Don't use regular expressions for such a trivial task. You can use PHP's [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) (possibly with `"\n"` as the second parameter) or [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (like `substr($string, 0, -1)`) or MySQL's [`RTRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim).

Comment: I like this answer much better

Comment: rtrim("\n") didn't work for me. $string = preg_replace('/\n$/','',$string); worked just fine.